# How to exclude directory from make check

Tags: compilation, autotools

I use some third party library in my project which I need to compile into the code. But I want to ***not*** run make check in the subdirectory of the library.

How can I achieve this?

Right now, I am including the library by adding a line

```
SUBDIRS += libsomelibrary
```

to Makefile.am.

Comment: The easiest and cleanest solution would be to remove the checks/tests from the third party library.

Other solutions are very ugly and would require hacking the Makefile.in to redefine "RECURSIVE_TARGETS" by removing "check-recursive" and to define your own "check-recursive" to be a copy of the original minus the subdir in the list variable.

Comment: Sounds good. Make it an answer and I will accept it ;)